# How to pass value from Javascript to Wicket?

Tags: javascript, java, wicket, wicket-7

I have Javascript method, that performs some business logic at client end and returns a values.
Now I need this value in my wicket page.
What is the best way to go about this?

**P.S.** I am using Wicket 7.

Comment: Could you give more details about your scenario? Is JavaScript called from Wicket page and how do you want to use the returned value?

Comment: @AndreaDelBene I have a Javascript that runs on client browser and collects some info, I want that info to be passed to the Wicket page, so that I can do further processing with that data.

Comment: Do you need this data for rendering the page?

Answer (score 2):

You could write an [`AbstractAjaxBehaviour`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/7.x/org/apache/wicket/behavior/AbstractAjaxBehavior.html) that calls your javascript function and passes it back with ajax to the `callbackUrl`

See [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19561485/461499) here for more detail.

In the `respond(AjaxRequestTarget target)` you can update any component in the page that need updating.

For example, you could run a behavior that tests WebGL support via Javascript, pass it back to the `Page` via the `Behavior` and use the value to replace a placeholder or fallback `Panel` with a fancy `WebGL` version.

Answer (score 0):

Wicket components are rendered on the server side so you don't have access to them from JavaScript after a page was rendered.

If you want to send some data to the server just  use Ajax request or submit the form.

Comment: Wickets links and behaviors expose information to the browser to detect where the user clicked etc, so in that sense you do have access to them.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider to use a [custom resource](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/single.html#_custom_resources). Once you have collected the user data with JavaScript, you can send them via ajax to the custom resource mounted at a [specific path](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/single.html#_mounting_resources). Additional data processing  can be done in the custom resource and you can display the result once the ajax request has finished.